# How to change format of created_at and updated_at in laravel Model?

Tags: laravel, datetime

In laravel response I want to get values of "created_at" and 'updated_at" like this format (without seconds):

```
2022-02-22 04:07
```

I try to use :

```
protected $casts = [
    'created_at'  => 'datetime:Y-m-d H:i',
    'updated_at' => 'datetime:Y-m-d H:i'
];
```

But not works, the datetime stills in default format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
public function getCreatedAtAttribute($date)
{
    return Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date)->format('Y-m-d H:i');
}

public function getUpdatedAtAttribute($date)
{
    return Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date)->format('Y-m-d H:i');
}
```

use these

Comment: Thanks, I try it but the same.

Comment: Do you have any other thing going on? Can you get your model and call ->toArray() and dd it?

Comment: no, everything is fine, but the created_at and updated_at attributes of the returned object still remain in the default format.

Comment: Can you put dd inside your getCreatedAtAttribute? To check if is it working?

Comment: I do it, the method does not called. When I tried to call it manually in my controller it works.

`$client->getCreatedAtAttribute('2022-02-22 04:07:10');`

and here is what dd display :
`"2022-02-22 04:07"`

Comment: Are you trying to check created_at value directly in model like dd ing it? Can you try it in a response when you send to your frontend or view? Without adding dd or anything. Just use Laravel's response and your object. It should return it. If you use it $model->created_at it should also work. It does not work if you directly dd your model.

Comment: Yes I do, it return this value : 
`"2022-02-28T15:21:28.000000Z"`

Comment: Can you use toArray() at the end of your chain. Can you share your controller code? It should work I just tried in clean install of Laravel.

Comment: `use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Client;

class ClientController extends Controller
{

    public function allClients() 
    {
        $clients = DB::table('clients')->get();

        //$clients = Client::all();
        return $clients;

        // $client = new Client();
        // $client->getCreatedAtAttribute('2022-02-22 04:07:10');
        
    }`

Comment: Man, Come on! You are using DB instance. Not Laravel Model. Just Use $client = Client::first(); and then use $client->created_at;

Comment: I use `$clients = Client::all();` but not work also.

Comment: Did you try to get Client::all()->first()->created_at ? If you did not use Laravel Model it wont work. Also, If you did not send it to front end like toArray() or to json etc. it won't work either. If it is worked, please do not forget to mark as answer and upvote.

Comment: it works with only one element but I wanted it to be work for all records.

Comment: It will work for every element when you call them.

Comment: Please mark as an aswer and upvote my answer.

Answer (score 3):

If your 'created_at' and 'updated_at' fields are date time object or carbon instance you can simply do

```
 public function getCreatedAtAttribute($date)
  {
    return  $date->format('Y-m-d H:i');
 }

 public function getUpdatedAtAttribute($date)
 {
   return $date->format('Y-m-d H:i');
 }
```

if its neither date time object nor carbon instance you need to either convert your string to date time instance as @gguney answered .

You can also define the field inside

```
protected $dates  = [ 'created_at' , 'updated_at'];
```

Note : The formatted values only reflect while you print the data or dump if the field is inside some array or collection you cannot see the format as these method will be called just before printing the specific field.